# Name of path-bar inside website showing current position

Tags: html, web

Which is the name of this kind of "path-bar" mostly located on the upper left side of a webpage showing you the current position inside the website?

[image]

Comment: they are called breadcrumbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called breadcrumbs.
It is not a standard HTML element, but UI you can add to the page.

Here is the bootstrap version:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/breadcrumb/